# In Wordpress, is there a way to make the navigation drop down menu show posts in a category?

Tags: php, wordpress

On a Wordpress website where you configure the navigation bar and you can show categories, and put child categories underneath the parents, is there a way to make it so that when someone hovers over the top level category that the drop down that pops up shows the individual posts within that category? And then you can click the post and go to that single post page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin sounds like what you need.
http://wordpress.org/plugins/category-posts-in-custom-menu/

Comment: Looks like exactly what I need, will test it out and report back. Thanks bud.